# Java: How to print vector?

Tags: java, printing, vector

Java: How to print vector?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ed04VetorOrdenado {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int vet[] = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Digite 10 numeros:");
        for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) {
            vet[i] = entrada.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print("Vetor ordenado: ");
        ordenar(vet);
    }

    // Buble sort function
    static void ordenar(int[] v) {
        int troca;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < v.length; j++) {
                if (v[i] > v[j]) {
                    troca = v[j];
                    v[j] = v[i];
                    v[i] = troca;
                }
            }
            System.out.print(v[i] + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

I want print outside of FOR. Similar at

```
System.out.print(v);
```

Comment: Does `System.out.println(v);`? Else iterate through the elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an array, not a vector! However, here is how you print an array elements:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(v));
```

Comment: This requires you to `import java.util.Arrays;`